# What is a 'func' in PWM configuration?

Tags: pwm

To enable PWM on RPI, one needs to modify `/boot/config.txt`. I found nice examples of what line one should add for various cases: https://github.com/dotnet/iot/blob/main/Documentation/raspi-pwm.md

I do not understand the tables fully however.

Does the single/dual channel mean that we can either have just 1 PWM signal, or two (separate) PWM signals?

If I'd like to have 2 separate PWM signals on 2 pins, I'd probably use     `dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,pin=12,func=4,pin2=13,func2=4`.

What are `func` (and `func2`)? What's the difference between `func=2` and `func=4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in `/boot/overlays/README`

For PWM the GPIO must be in the correct mode.  That varies according to the GPIO.  Set the `func` according to the following table.

```
Name:   pwm
Info:   Configures a single PWM channel
        Legal pin,function combinations for each channel:
          PWM0: 12,4(Alt0) 18,2(Alt5) 40,4(Alt0)            52,5(Alt1)
          PWM1: 13,4(Alt0) 19,2(Alt5) 41,4(Alt0) 45,4(Alt0) 53,5(Alt1)
        N.B.:
          1) Pin 18 is the only one available on all platforms, and
             it is the one used by the I2S audio interface.
             Pins 12 and 13 might be better choices on an A+, B+ or Pi2.
          2) The onboard analogue audio output uses both PWM channels.
          3) So be careful mixing audio and PWM.
          4) Currently the clock must have been enabled and configured
             by other means.
Load:   dtoverlay=pwm,<param>=<val>
Params: pin                     Output pin (default 18) - see table
        func                    Pin function (default 2 = Alt5) - see above
        clock                   PWM clock frequency (informational)
```

```
Name:   pwm-2chan
Info:   Configures both PWM channels
        Legal pin,function combinations for each channel:
          PWM0: 12,4(Alt0) 18,2(Alt5) 40,4(Alt0)            52,5(Alt1)
          PWM1: 13,4(Alt0) 19,2(Alt5) 41,4(Alt0) 45,4(Alt0) 53,5(Alt1)
        N.B.:
          1) Pin 18 is the only one available on all platforms, and
             it is the one used by the I2S audio interface.
             Pins 12 and 13 might be better choices on an A+, B+ or Pi2.
          2) The onboard analogue audio output uses both PWM channels.
          3) So be careful mixing audio and PWM.
          4) Currently the clock must have been enabled and configured
             by other means.
Load:   dtoverlay=pwm-2chan,<param>=<val>
Params: pin                     Output pin (default 18) - see table
        pin2                    Output pin for other channel (default 19)
        func                    Pin function (default 2 = Alt5) - see above
        func2                   Function for pin2 (default 2 = Alt5)
        clock                   PWM clock frequency (informational)
```

Comment: Ok, so `func(2)` selects Alt0 or Alt5, as I understand. Alt0 and Alt5 use different pins for the outputs. However, why is it necessary? The `pin(2)` already selects the pin. It seems like `func` is a redundant setting?

Comment: I haven't checked but `func` may be a redundant setting for PWM (e.g. if there is only one legal `func` for PWM on a particular GPIO).  I know with serial you can use different `func` to select different serial hardware for GPIO 14/15.

Comment: I'm not seeing the answer to the OP's question. I stumbled on the above in the github page and couldn't understand what it was telling me. the answer amounts to "read the documentation". I'm still baffled.

Comment: In fairness, I'm not sure what the OPs question was. It may be "what are func, func2, func=2 and func=4?"